# PHP How to get value using the Class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have made a form with a description and inside that description there's a list called "services-list" and I need to get the value with the class "services-list"

here is the code on how I get the whole description section

```
<p class="card"><?php echo substr(strip_tags($row->description), 0, 200); ?>...</p>
```

description came from a form for="description", and saved to the database.

in that code there is a section which has class "services-list" and listed all the services, how can I call that specific section to print?

I am referring to code something like this

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($row->description .'.services-list'), 0, 200); ?>
```

but not sure with this code.

Comment: you're using JS(jquery)?

Comment: for this specific section, no.

Comment: unfortunately no you cannot specifically target the class using `strip_tags`, you'll need to use `DOMDocument` and extract the text inside that section

Comment: you should. `php` doesn't do such kind of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `$row->description` object contains this text :

```
$row = (object) [ 'description' => '
<div>
    <li class="other-class">Service A</li>
    <li class="services-list">Service B</li>
    <li class="services-list">Service C</li>
    <li class="services-list">Service D</li>
</div>
'];
```

You could use `DOMDocument` to get all of the `services-list` class element by :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($row->description);   

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$nodeList = $xpath->query("//li[@class='services-list']");
$node = $nodeList->item(1);

$service_list = [];
foreach ($nodeList as $i => $val){
    if (!empty($val->nodeValue)) {
        array_push($service_list, $val->nodeValue);
    }
}
$service_list = implode($service_list, ', '); // separate each item by comma

// To check the result:
echo "<p>" . $service_list . "</p>";
```

The output will be :

```
<p>Service B, Service C, Service D</p>
```